# SQL Server - Capture queries created in tempdb using Extended Events

Tags: sql-server

Our reporting platform extensively using creating temp tables (#tmp) to display data from multiple sources.

Using extended events we can capture growth events on tempdb, but 
Can we capture queries created in tempdb using extended events or DMVs.

Below Query covers all queries, I want it to capture all TEMPDB queries

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [Caputre ALL Queries] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.rpc_completed(
    ACTION(sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.database_id,sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.nt_username,sqlserver.query_hash,sqlserver.server_principal_name,sqlserver.session_id,sqlserver.sql_text)
   ),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_batch_completed(SET collect_batch_text=(1)
    ACTION(sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.database_id,sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.nt_username,sqlserver.query_hash,sqlserver.session_id)
    )

ADD TARGET package0.event_file
(
  SET FILENAME = 'F:\PerformanceLog\CaptureAllQueries.xel',
      MAX_FILE_SIZE = 32768,
      MAX_ROLLOVER_FILES = 10
),
--ADD TARGET package0.event_file(SET filename=N'Capture All Queries',max_file_size=(100)),
ADD TARGET package0.ring_buffer
WITH (MAX_MEMORY=4096 KB,EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=30 SECONDS,MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE,TRACK_CAUSALITY=ON,STARTUP_STATE=OFF)
GO
```

Comment: Do you have extended events sessions that capture queries *not* in tempdb?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I have added code which im trying

Comment: The problem is it's very hard to identify queries that are touching tempdb, because unless it's a simple `create #tmp; select from #tmp;` it is likely the context is a different db, it's joining against other tables in other databases, etc. Many of the DMVs that keep track of sessions either keep track of the context DB or they have to pick a database that is impacted by a multi-database query. It means that if you filter out queries to only include those that are explicitly exposed as tempdb, you're going to miss a lot.

Comment: https://sqlperformance.com/2014/05/t-sql-queries/dude-who-owns-that-temp-table

Comment: You wrote the above queries, will it help to capture...

Comment: Yes, if you are running those queries all the time, you can capture data about who has created temp tables. But tempdb is the dumping ground for *lots* and *lots* of query work that might never touch a temp table. Again, you can capture some stuff, but you're going to have a real hard time being sure you're capturing **all** stuff.